# Maximum path cost in matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

Can anyone tell the algorithm for finding the maximum path cost in a `NxM` matrix starting from top left corner and ending with bottom right corner with left ,right , down  movement is allowed in a matrix and contains negative cost. A cell can be visited any number of times and after visiting a cell its cost is replaced with 0

**Constraints**
1 <= nxm <= 4x10^6
**INPUT**

```
4 5
1 2 3 -1 -2
-5 -8 -1 2 -150
1 2 3 -250 100
1 1 1 1 20
```

**OUTPUT**

```
37
```

Explanation is given in the image
[Explanation of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvMrC.jpg)

Comment: Is there any constraint? maximum value of N and M?

Comment: In in the image it seems you can loop. If this is possible, then infinite is the correct answer.

Comment: 1<=nxm<= 4 x 10^6 is the constraints @PhamTrung and SaiBot there is always an answer not an infinite value

Comment: @SaiBot `after visiting a cell its cost is replaced with 0` => this condition rules out the possibility of infinite

Comment: @גלעדברקן revisiting the cell doesn't reset the total and no impact is made to the total path cost as it is adding 0 to it

Comment: @AlgorithimicDUMB My friend you are asking support for solving a problem in Hacker Rank contest, week 35   https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w35/challenges/matrix-land, I do not know if it against the contest rules. It would be more fair to solve it without SO direct support

Comment: @aberna it is against SO rules to post a question from an ongoing contest, but the link you provided leads to 404, "page not found," for me, and so cannot confirm this is from a live contest.

Comment: @גלעדברקן You are right it is a contest with an authentication procedure. Here it is a screenshot http://ibb.co/kf0VCm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be from an ongoing contest according to aberna

Comment: @גלעדברקן I confirm it. More than this same user had the same issue in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129682/longest-palindromic-substring-to-be-small-as-possible

Comment: @aberna Heh, OP even got the question wrong. According to the picture in your comment, starting position can be anywhere in the first row, and ending position anywhere in the last row.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have also negative costs then use bellman-ford. What you do is that you change sign of all the costs(convert negative signs to positive and positive to negative) then find the shortest path and this path will be the longest because you have changed the signs.

If the sign is never becoms negative then use dijkstra shrtest-path but before that make all values negative and this will return you the longest path with it's cost.

You matrix is a direct graph. In your image you are trying to find a path(max or min) from index (0,0) to (n-1,n-1).

You need these things to represent it as a graph.

- You need a linkedlist and in each node you have a `first_Node, second_Node,Cost to move from first node to second`.
- An array of linkedlist. In each array index you save a linkedlist.If for example there is a path from 0 to 5 and 0 to 1(it's an undirected graph) then your graph will look like this.
  [image]

If you want a direct-graph then simply add in adj[0] = 5 and do not add in adj[5] = 0 , this means that there is path from 0 to 5 but not from 5 to zero.

Here linkedlist represents only nodes which are connected not there cost. You have to add extra variable there which keep cost for each two nodes and it will look like this.

[image]

Now instead of first linkedlist put this linkedlist in your array and you have a graph now to run shortest or longest path algorithm.

If you want an intellgent algorithm then you can use A* with heuristic, i guess manhattan will be best.

If cost of your edges is not negative then use Dijkstra.

If cost is negative then use bellman-ford algorithm.

You can always find the longest path by converting the minus sign to plus and plus to minus and then run shortest path algorithm. Path founded will be longest.

I answered this question and as you said in comments to look at point two. If that's a task then main idea of this assignment is ensure the `Monotonocity`.

- h stands for heuristic cost.
- A  stands for accumulated cost.

Which says that each node the `h(A) =< h(A) + A(A,B)`. Means if you want to move from `A` to `B` then cost should not be decreasing(can you do something with your values such that this property will hold) but increasing and once you satisfy this condition then everyone node which A* chooses , that node will be part of your path from source to Goal because this is the path with shortest/longest value.

**pathMax** You can enforece monotonicity. If there is path from `A` to `B` such that f(S...AB) < f(S ..B) then set cost of the  f(S...AB) = Max(f(S...AB) , f(S...A)) where S means source.

Comment: It seems non-trivial to build the graph on which you want to run B-F/Dijkstra. How would you model edge weights in each particular row, when revisiting cells is worth 0?

Comment: Can u be a bit more elaborative

Comment: @tucuxi i have editted and your node is (0,0) not 1 and the matrix he posted is cost of node so you can add them up by moving from 1 to 2 to anyother connected node.In this case the cost of node will be update and we call it Accumulated cost.

Comment: Is it possible to construct an adjacency list from the matrix I specified, coz if i use rows and columns as the nodes then it would be absolutely different with mat[0][1] and mat[0][2] being in different path. If i am wrong pls correct me. Help me with the adjacency matrix a bit

Comment: Why is that not possible? @AlgorithimicDUMB You define which nodes are connected by putting them in a linkedlist associated with each array index

Comment: Pls provide a n algorithm for it

Comment: @LuaiGhunim, seem that you are correct about using bellman-ford, but i am wondering, if i need to translate the matrix into the adjList and its cost, how about convert Mat[0][0], Mat[1][1], Mat[i][i]? Should make adjList[i].push(i, i, A[i][i])? Is this correct? Then how can i just move to right, left of down?

Comment: yes that's correct, you say that your node is connected with the next one like 0 is connected to 1 and then 4 if the matrix is 3x3 , you simply add in adj list adj[i].push(i,i+1,cost) where i=0 and i+1 = 1 and cost is simply cost of 0.

Comment: Then you do it again like this adj[i].push(i,i+size,cost) here i+size is 0+3 = 3 which is a node down to zero is matrix is 3*3.  You run a loop for all number in matrix wth these two function.

Comment: Ok, so with given matrix, we have total 20 node? Then the edges could be bigger, Is it right? I made the adjList with left, right, down movable, but when i run bell-man ford, seem the result is not correct, it is just correct if i made only right and down movable. Do you know what is problem in here?

Comment: @user3693423 did you invert the values?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim sure i have just used the available Bellman algorithm. The problem is when we start travel from different node, an adjacency cost will be plus multiple times.  Can i chat with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159357/discussion-between-luai-ghunim-and-user3693423).

Answer (score 2):

Since moving up is not allowed, paths always look like a set of horizontal intervals that share at least 1 position (for the down move). Answers can be characterized as, say

```
struct Answer {
   int layer[N][2]; // layer[i][0] and [i][1] represent interval start&end
                    // with 0 <= layer[i][0] <= layer[i][1] < M
                    // layer[0][0] = 0, layer[N][1] = M-1
                    // and non-empty intersection of layers i and i+1 
};
```

An alternative encoding is to note only layer widths and offsets to each other; but you would still have to make sure that the last layer includes the exit cell.

Assuming that you have a `maxLayer` routine that finds the highest-scoring interval in each layer (const `O(M)` per layer), and that all such such layers overlap, this would yield an `O(N+M)` optimal answer. However, it may be necessary to expand intervals to ensure that overlap occurs; and there may be multiple highest-scoring intervals in a given layer. At this point I would model the problem as a directed graph:

- each layer has one node per score-maximizing horizontal continuous interval.
- nodes from one layer are connected to nodes in the next layer according to the cost of expanding both intervals to achieve at least 1 overlap. If they already overlap, the cost is 0. Edge costs will always be zero or negative (otherwise, either source or target intervals could have scored higher by growing bigger). Add the (expanded) source-node interval value to the connection cost to get an "edge weight".

You can then run Dijkstra on this graph (negate edge weights so that the "longest path" is returned) to find the optimal path. Even better, since all paths pass once and only once through each layer, you only need to keep track of the best route to each node, and only need to build nodes and edges for the layer you are working on.

**Implementation details ahead**

- to calculate maxLayer in O(M), use [Kadane's Algorithm](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Kadane%27s_Algorithm), modified to return all maximal intervals instead of only the first. Where the linked algorithm discards an interval and starts anew, you would instead keep a copy of that contender to use later.
- given the sample input, the maximal intervals would look like this:

  ```
                       [0]
   1  2  3   -1   -2   [1 2 3]
  -5 -8 -1    2 -150 =>        [2]
   1  2  3 -250  100   [1 2 3]     [100]
   1  1  1    1   20   [1 1 1   1    20]
                                     [0]
  ```
- given those intervals, they would yield the following graph:

  ```
      (0)
        |  =>0
      (+6)
         \ -1=>5 
          \    
          (+2)
      =>7/    \ -150=>-143
        /      \
     (+7)      (+100)
   =>12 \      / =>-43
         \    /
          (+24)
            |  =>37
           (0)
  ```
- when two edges incide on a single node (row 1 1 1 1 20), carry forward only the highest incoming value.

Comment: Can u explain a little bit on the construction of the layer array in the structure . How to formulate the layer array from the inputs?

Answer (score 2):

For each element in a row, find the maximum cost that can be obtained if we move horizontally across the row, given that we go through that element.

Eg. For the row

```
1 2 3 -1 -2
```

The maximum cost for each element obtained if we move horizontally given that we pass through that element will be

```
6 6 6 5 3
```

Explanation:

for element 3: we can move backwards horizontally touching 1 and 2. we will not move horizontally forward as the values -1 and -2, reduces the cost value.

So the maximum cost for 3 = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

The maximum cost matrix for each of elements in a row if we move horizontally, for the input you have given in the description will be

```
6     6    6    5      3  
-5   -7    1    2      -148  
6     6    6    -144   100  
24    24   24   24     24
```

Since we can move vertically from one row to the below row, update the maximum cost for each element as follows:

```
cost[i][j] = cost[i][j] + cost[i-1][j]
```

So the final cost matrix will be :

```
6    6    6     5      3 
1    -1   7     7      -145 
7    5    13    -137   -45  
31   29   37    -113   -21
```

Maximum value in the last row of the above matrix will be give you the required output i.e 37

Comment: Cool solution. How to build the initial cost matrix

Comment: How do you find max cost for each element?

Comment: This is just wrong. For example, the best achievable cost for the rightmost element in the second row is not `-145` but `-143` if we go `R-R-R-D-R => 1+2+3-1+2-150`. The problem is this solution assumes you can only arrive at an element from above, which is of course not the case.